# React Native Navigation children parent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, navigation

I've been trying to make a navigation component, but am facing an error.

Here is the architecture for my StackNavigation view:

```js
const App = createStackNavigator({
    Register:{
        screen:Registration,
    },
    Home: {
        screen: SwipeNavigator({

            Home: {
                screen: Record,
                left: 'QRcode',
                right: 'Conv',
                top: 'Profil',

            },

            QRcode: {
                screen: QRcode,
                type:'push'
            },

            Conv: {
                screen: Conversation,
                type:'push'
            },
            Profil: {
                screen: Profil,
                type:'push'
            },



        }),
        navigationOptions: {
            header: null,
        },
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, when I am in the SwipeNavigator I can't go to register. I get an error indicating this.props.navigation is undefined.

Does anyone know why I'm facing this error and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance for you response

Answer (score 0):

I have a great solution for you to solve all `this.props.navigation` problems :) I've just copy/paste my previous answer from another question. It explains how to use it and how you can do it with new React Navigation Helper. If you have any question with that, I'm here to help. It will just fix your whole navigation problem.

> I have created a library for handling navigation problem and also
>   prevent the usage of this.props.navigation prop.
>
> ### [React Navigation Helpers](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-navigation-helpers)
>
> Usage is very simple. On your App.js or your navigator simply set the
>   global level navigator.
>
> ```
> import NavigationService from "react-navigation-helpers";
>
>
> <MainNavigator
>   ref={navigatorRef =>
>     NavigationService.setGlobalLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)
>   }
> />
> ```
>
> Then you use ANYWHERE on your project with this simple code segment:
>
> ```
> NavigationService.navigate("home")
> ```
>
> Of course, you still need to import the NavigationService :)
>
> You can find a more detailed document on the library's README. If you
>   still have a question, feel free to ask, I will help you gladly.

Comment: In my case I don't understand how to use it :/

Comment: You just simply put a global navigator and it will handle all the things about navigation. You cannot access this.props.navigation everywhere right now?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`?

Comment: Okay then you can use it. Can you check my example in this library. I believe that you can do it. It is really simple, only need to set the main navigator's reference